# How to create a feature diagram?

Tags: uml, diagram

I have a big side project that I do now for 3 years. It has a lot of extra small tools to help me do tasks. Most of those tools are so old that I forgot what I have there.

How to create a feature diagram to have easy reminder of what features are available ?

Is there some special UML diagram notation for it?

How to do it? I think graphic version would be better than a readme text file.

Comment: It almost sounds like a flow diagram, like the ones helpdesk employees use to solve a problem.

Comment: Feature Diagram is not a standard UML diagram but some UML tools provide such functionality. what UML tool are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Normally features are shown in use case diagrams in UML.

The use cases can later be used for creating sequence diagrams etc.